# How do I get sound in Trine on 12.04 64-Bit?

Tags: 12.04, sound, 64-bit, pulseaudio

Whenever I try to play Trine, it starts but I get no sound. In the terminal this error message appears:

```
/o/g/trine> ./trine-launcher64 
ALSA lib conf.c:3314:(snd_config_hooks_call) Cannot open shared library libasound_module_conf_pulse.so
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
```

I have libasound2-plugins installed, which contains libasound_module_conf_pulse.so, how can I get Trine to recognize it?

I tried starting the 32-Bit version with linux32 as well, it crashes.

Comment: See also this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/142956/installing-old-loki-games-on-12-04-64-bit-results-in-no-audio

Comment: I can just preload it to make the error message go away, but sound still does not work: env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so ./trine-bin64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preloading *did* solve my problem:

```
env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_conf_pulse.so  ./trine-launcher
```

but alsa then played back using the wrong soundcard. Messing around in the sound settings fixed that issue. I don't know why everything else played back fine even if I apparently had the wrong output selected in the sound settings?

Answer (score 1):

I run raring 64 bit and solved this issue (no sound) by switching to surroundsound 5.1 as described here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SurroundSound

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.